# Share a variable between newman pre-request script and custom reporter

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, newman

I have a newman command that sends a request every 15 seconds, and one of the parameter in the request is incremented by 1 every time. I have created a custom newman reporter which is a Node JS program to print only the response body. 
I need to change my program such that after a certain response, the request parameter will increment by 50 otherwise increment by 1. 
The pre-request script has access to postman's environment and global variables only but no access to system environment variables and I am unable to read a temp file in this script. On the other hand, the custom reporter can do anything that a Node JS program can, but can't set postman's environment variables.
Anyone has any ideas what could be a probable solution?

Pre-request code:

```
    conNo = postman.getGlobalVariable('consumer_number');
    newConNum = Number.parseInt(conNo) + 1;
    if(newConNum.toString().length == 12) {
       postman.setGlobalVariable('consumer_number',newConNum);
    } else {
        postman.setGlobalVariable('consumer_number','number_exceeded_12_digits');
    }
```

Reporter code:

```
function CustomNewmanReporter (newman, reporterOptions, collectionRunOptions) {

    newman.on('request', function (err, obj) {

      if (err) {
        console.log('Error occurred.');
        return; 
     }

     fs = require('fs');

     var successStream = fs.createWriteStream('success.txt', {flags: 'a'});
     var failStream  = fs.createWriteStream('fail.txt', {flags: 'a'});    

    if(obj.response.responseSize > 40) {
        successStream.write("\n" + JSON.stringify(obj.request.url.query) + ":" + Buffer.from(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.response.stream)).data).toString('utf8'));
    } else {
        failStream.write("\n" + JSON.stringify(obj.request.url.query) + ":" + Buffer.from(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.response.stream)).data).toString('utf8'));
    }

    successStream.end();
    failStream.end();

    });

}
```

Comment: Can you share your pre-request code please? You're talking about a code based problem but not showing any code.

Comment: Added the code.